# In Joomla how to change the module mod_news_show_gk3?

Tags: joomla

How can I change the mod_news_show_gk3 module to:

- Change the size of the post image. It uses the first image of the post, but it seems to not be resizing the image.
- Add an extra field: It is important to show in the main page what is the source of the post. I would then like to add an extra field during post editing time, namely "source", and then I would like to show the source below the title and before the text.
- Change the title size. Title is oversized and I couldn't find any way to decrease its size.
- Add a border around the section.

Here is the address: `http://central.antinovaordemmundial.com/`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using Gavick news pro  Gk3, you better of ask the community there but here are few hints
Change size of post image, needs to be defined in the Php file (if it is img tag, if it is background image then you need to resize the image.

Definitely needs the code editing in php file. But actually doesn't the image link to the source which actually is the post. Also it shows the title of post on hovering i suppose.

in `/modules/mod_smooth_gallery_camp26/smooth_gallery/jd.gallery.css`

find the class declaration like below and change the font-size to something like 12px

```
    .jdGallery .slideInfoZone h2 {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 18px;
      ...
      padding-top: 0;
    }
```

I don;t see any sections in the image rotators, could you tell more